# I'm trying to send text in java to a website, and get text back

Tags: java

I have little to no experience in URL browsing/connections and stuff, but from the stuff I've read so far it doesn't seem too hard.

What I'm trying to do is I have a string of text inputted from the user [DONE] and inside a String variable. I then try to open a connection to http://www.gizoogle.net/textilizer.php, input the string, click translate, then read the string again and save it back in my class as another string, then output it. I'm kind of lost, and was wondering if anyone would be so kind as to help. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: Hello sir, people are going to harass you about seeing some code! The idea is that you try first... get stuck... then we help you make it work.

Comment: @d'alar'cop    The thing is that I don't even know where to start; even after researching and looking around...

Comment: look up how to do POST requests. based on the page source, I think you'll need to pass the text to translate via the "translatetext" variable. you don't actually do any webpage rendering/clicking